# Join в MySQL с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу MiniCRM, у меня есть 3 таблицы, users, roles and pages, каждая page имеет поле roles, что означает что у каждой страницы есть роли, которые имеют к ней доступ(пока что понял так), и суть заключается в том, что с помощью Join я вывожу роли, которые имеют доступ к этой странице, и вот что я получаю

```
        [id] => 3
        [title] => 1
        [url] => 1
        [roles] => 1, 2, 3, 4
        [created_at] => 2023-12-14 04:37:22
        [updated_at] => 2023-12-14 04:37:22
        [role_name] => Пользователь
```

roles - это те самые роли, которые имеют доступ к этой странице, а с помощью Join я хочу получить имена, которые имеют доступ к этой странице, но MySQL мне выводит только имя роли с role_id => 1, а 2 3 4 она игнорирует. Как я должен составлять запрос, или как это можно реализовать?

Вот как выглядит мой запрос:

```
SELECT a.*, b.role_name FROM pages AS a JOIN roles AS b ON a.roles = b.id
```

Comment: нужна еще одна таблица, связывающая роли и страницы, многие ко многим

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: А поле roles в таблице pages - оно у вас какого типа?

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko вы конечно не поверите, но строку вида 1, 2, 3, 4 можно хранить только в поле строкового типа ;-)